Property 'results' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<MovieResponse>'. TypeScript Error
I'm currently using this TMDB endpoint in my Angular 18 application and setting it to a variable.
This is how it looks:
private trendingMovies$ = this.http.get<MovieResponse>(${this.apiUrl}trending/movie/day, this.options).pipe(
    map((data) => {
      data.results.map((movie: Movie) => ({
        ...movie,
      }) as Movie)
    }),
    shareReplay(1),
  );

but I'm getting this typescript error for the results property on the data object in my map operator:
Property 'results' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<MovieResponse>'.
  Property 'results' does not exist on type 'HttpSentEvent'.ts(2339)

This is the interface I am using for the response and also the interface for the individual object within the array of results within the response:
export interface MovieResponse {
  page: Number;
  results: Movie[];
  total_pages: Number;
  total_results: Number;
}

export interface Movie {
  adult: boolean;
  backdrop_path: string;
  genre_id: Number[];
  id: Number;
  media_type: string;
  original_language: string;
  original_title: string;
  overview: string;
  popularity: Number;
  poster_path: string;
  release_date: string;
  title: string;
  video: boolean;
  vote_average: Number;
  vote_count: Number;
}

I've used the tap operator to log the response to the console and it clearly has a results property so I'm not sure why I am getting this typescript error or how to fix it?
I've tried adding adding a type to this line but it still displays the same error:
map((data: MovieResponse) => {

Any help is appreciated.

Try with data[‘results’].map((movie)

Can you share the options code?

Try adding observeOn: 'body', I think that is causing the issue. With type of observe as response, the type gets set to HttpEvent<MovieResponse> which is causing the issue.
Before:
private trendingMovies$ = this.http
    .get<MovieResponse>(`${this.apiUrl}trending/movie/day`, { observe: 'response' })

After:
private trendingMovies$ = this.http
    .get<MovieResponse>(`${this.apiUrl}trending/movie/day`, { observe: 'body' })

Stackblitz Demo

You should add the type of the variable data:
map((data:MovieResponse ) => ...
//or
map((data:any) => ...

But your map have not any logic. map is used to transform the response (and always you should return the value
   map((data) => {
      data.results.map((movie: Movie) => ({
        ...movie,
      }) as Movie)
      return data //<--else you transform in null the response
    })

anyway, this "map" don't make anything. Remember that you use typescript but this typescript "transpile" to javaScript, so the "types" only help you to don't makes errors, not to be sure the response is the type you indicate

Thanks for the responses, they helped me get the code working. I believe my problem was in the options object that was attached to the request.
private options = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/json',
      Authorization: '<auth token here'
    }
  }

I removed the method property as I realised it was redundant and the error stopped appearing.
